# Почта для root отравляется в /var/mail/mail

Tags: linux, unix, sendmail

Написал скрипт, который проверяет целостность файла и в случае изменений, отправляет на почту root сообщение. Однако вместо почтового ящика рута письмо лежит в /var/mail/mail. В /etc/aliases root: root. В чем может быть проблема?

Comment: А не для рута вообще отправляется почта? попробуйте из консоли выполнить sendmail -f "your@email.ru" -v "user@email.ru"

Comment: @Dmitriy не для рута всё работает

Comment: ну так укажите, куда во внешний мир должны отправляться сообщения. [`$ man aliases`](http://www.opennet.ru/man.shtml?category=5&russian=&topic=aliases)

Answer (score 0):

Поправка - почта отправлялась с помощью утилиты mail.

Теперь к сути. С её помощью в Debian прислать письмо на ящик root не выйдет. Может, есть способ, но я так и не нашел. Но посколько отправить письмо мне требовалось, то я применил весьма грубое решение - с помощью incrontab. Как только происходит изменение в файле /var/mail/mail - его содержимое копируется в /var/mail/root. Решение не блещет элегантностью, но меня спасло.